# How to modify the title bar in elementary desktop?

Tags: 12.04, titlebar, elementary, elementary-theme

I installed Elementary desktop in Ubuntu 12.04.
but for some reason the title bar retains the theme of Ubuntu.
any advice for this? Can it can be changed?

[image: title bar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gnome tweak solved the problem. Ubuntu tweak strangely not change the theme of the title bar